# The Retrofit GET method isn't getting the result from the API

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to GET some datas FROM an API of Currency Converter. Even passing the right GET URL the "response.body" in coming with null values.

I'm using the Currency Converter API from the website RAPIDAPI (https://rapidapi.com/solutionsbynotnull/api/currency-converter18/)

> The Retrofit Endpoint:

```
interface CurrencyConverterEndpoint {

    @GET("api/v1/convert")
    fun getCurrencyConverter(@Query("from") from: String, @Query("to") to: String, @Query("amount") amount: String): Call<ConvertModel>

}
```

> The Model of the result from the request:

```
data class ConvertModel (
    @SerializedName("from")
    val from: String,
    @SerializedName("to")
    val to: String,
    @SerializedName("amountToConvert")
    val amountToConvert: Int,
    @SerializedName("convertedAmount")
    val convertedAmount: Double
    )
```

```
fun getCurrencyConverter(
    from: String,
    to: String,
    amount: String,
    listener: RetrofitListener<ConvertModel>
) {
    val getCurrencyConverterCallback = endpoint.getCurrencyConverter(from, to, amount)
    getCurrencyConverterCallback.enqueue(object : Callback<ConvertModel> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ConvertModel>, response: Response<ConvertModel>) {
            if (response.code() == RetrofitConstants.SUCCESS) {
                val s = response
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConvertModel>, t: Throwable) {
            listener.onError(t.message ?: "Erro.")
        }

    })
}
```

[The result from the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyBwi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API expect `key` and `host` from you. The proper method should be like below:

```
interface CurrencyConverterEndpoint {

    @GET("api/v1/convert")
    fun getCurrencyConverter(
        @Header("X-RapidAPI-Key") token: String = "your API key",
        @Header("X-RapidAPI-Host") host: String = "currency-converter18.p.rapidapi.com",
        @Query("from") from: String,
        @Query("to") to: String,
        @Query("amount") amount: String
    ): Call<ConvertModel>

}
```

Comment: Using the headers in the ENDPOINT even can access the server.
I'm already passing the HEADERS key in the interceptor of retrofit, and It's working because um using other ENDPOINT to GET the supported currencies and it's working. https://prnt.sc/dmF5HqROvOYo

Look in the print how the data comes with the headers as parameters the same as you recommended me: https://prnt.sc/R_u84_jfxBdR

Comment: UPDATE: I tried another API, and works! Looks like an API error. At least thank you for the support.